# Getter to a specified element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, getter

I have a class as following :

```
class Graph
{
private :
        vector<Graph*>              children;
        Board*                      tab;
[...]
public :
       vector<Graph*>               getchildren();
       Board*                       gettab();
[...]
}

Board*           Graph::gettab()        { return this->tab; }
vector<Graph*>   Graph::getchildren()   { return this->children; }
```

I need to do a loop that reach every tab inside children (in order to print them, to test if a method addChildren works).

I started by doing this :

```
for(vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = tree.getchildren().begin(); itr != tree.getchildren().end(); ++itr){
            //huh... Help ?
            }
```

My problem is, now, how do i access the tabs inside vector ? I have and iterator that "select" each graph in the vector returned by getchildren, but the iterator don't have the methods. A line like itr.gettab(); will obviously won't work, and tree.getchildren().itr.Graph::gettab(); tell me that tree doesn't have an itr member.

What should i do ? Create an itr member in Graph ?

Comment: Every call to `tree.getchildren()` returns a new vector. `tree.getchildren().begin()` and `tree.getchildren().end()` are iterators into different vectors (which, to boot, are dead by the time you get to actually dereference `itr`).

Comment: @Praetorian `itr` is not a `graph*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = tree.getchildren().begin()`

`*itr` is a `Graph*`

So you may call `(*itr)->gettab()`.

Also, you need to store the vector in a local variable before your for loop.

```
std::vector<Graph*> children = tree.getchildren();

for(std::vector<Graph*>::iterator itr = children.begin();
    itr != children.end();
    ++itr)
{
    Graph* graph = *itr;
    graph->gettab();
    (*itr)->gettab();
}
```

A simpler way in C++11, neither requiring iterators nor a local vector:

```
for (Graph* graph : tree.getchildren()) {
    graph->gettab();
}
```

**Note**: As mentioned in comment

```
vector<Graph*> getchildren();
```

should be

```
vector<Graph*>& getchildren();
```

If you're doing this, you don't need the local variable anymore.

Comment: As Igor pointed out in the comments, `begin()` and `end()` are called on two vector copies, which needs to be fixed... Your C++11 code fixes this of course, but the other one needs a local variable, or a reference should be returned by `getchildren()`.

Comment: Jarod42 @leemes thanks a lot for the (*itr)-> that compile now. As leemes and Igor Tandetnik said, there is a problem with the begin() and end() (program crash after too much iterations actually). Do you know how to do it without C++11 ? What do you need by need one local variable, i didn't get it.

Comment: @Csi: your getter should return reference to vector.

Comment: or add a local variable just before the loop: `vector<Graph*> children = tree.getchildren()` and then continue to work with the variable `children`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Jarod42 after returning reference to vector, program crash after 4 iterations (which is the maximum possible size of my vector<Graph*>. Is there any other error in the loop ? I may be an error from my addNode function, i dunno.  EDIT : After trying with leemes' local variable, i still got the same crash after 4 iterations. I think it comes from my addNode method. :(

Comment: Just for the record: you only need the local variable (like my edit of the answer) if you're *not* returning a reference. If you're returning a reference, you shouldn't need the local variable.

Comment: @leemes I tried by returning a reference and with both reference return and local variable, i still got the crash after exacly 4 iterations (maximum possible size of vector). I think the crash comes from somewhere else, because the tabs in the vector doesn't match the tabs created (i print them too) and supposed to put in vector (there is always the same tab in the vector, this is always children[0]). There is 2 possibilities, the loop is false and i can print only children[0] and crash, or it's my addNode method who is false and create crashes. I trust you guys for the loop, it's the method